# Google Search Operator: Does "-nofollow" exclude websites where links are nofollow?

Tags: google-search

I've seen someone using search operator `-nofollow` to find websites where links are dofollow and he claimed that this query can exclude websites whose HTML source code contains `nofollow`.

Well, personally I've tried a couple of times with `-nofollow` but still can find nofollow websites.

I can't help but wonder, does it work for real?

According to [this support page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861):

> Add a dash (-) before a word or site to exclude all **results** that include that word.

In other words, does "**results**" include HTML source code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "results" does _not_ include HTML code. I seem to recall a tool that let you see what Googlebot sees, and it only sees the text of a page (excepting meta tag instructions). If I can dig up a source I'll turn this into a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that search operator would not work as nofollow is used as a link relationship. Search operators don't check against markup but only visible content at the front end - the same search functionality that the search engine uses...

No idea why this was migrated from webmasters stack exchange. It belongs there... Not at web applications.